# Dynamically defining class properties in Swift

Tags: swift, class, properties, static

I have a class `Population` which upon initialisation gets defined a `language`. For the sake of this example, every member of that population only speaks this particular language. I then have a `Member` class defined within the `Population` for the population members. In this class, I would like to store the language as a static type property to be able to reference if from `Member` methods like in the example code below.

This seems more efficient to me than (a) always have to pass the `language` as a parameter when I call a method on a `members` element or (b) to store the language on each `Member` instance. However, below code does not quite seem to work and I wonder how to best implement this. Any ideas / best-practices? Apologies if this may sound rather trivial or in case I am completely on the wrong path here.

```
class Population {
    var language: String
    var members: [Member]
    
    init(language: String) {
        self.language = language
        for _ in 1...10 {members.append(Member())}
    }
    
    class Member {
        static let language: String
        
        func speak() {
            switch self.language {
                case "english": print("speak some english")
            }
        }
        
        func write() {
            switch self.language {
                case "english": print("write some english")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/where-and-how-to-use-static-variable-in-swift I am not sure what isn't working but from you verbiage I think you are misunderstanding `static`, `class` and reference types.

Comment: So do you want each member to be able to speak different language or you want everybody in population speak the same language?

Comment: "This seems more efficient to me than (a) always have to pass the language as a parameter" - it's not! The best way is to provide a default value to object property, and allow changing it later.

Comment: It would be that every member of the population speaks one language - the language of the population. Obviously this is just for the sake of the example and wouldn't make sense in reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some confusion about what `static` means, and it probably stems from `class Member` being nested in `class Population`.   All nesting types do is enclose the nested type in a namespace, which helps a) avoid name collision on types in global scope, and b) enables you to hide it as an implementation detail of the type in which it is nested, if you choose to make it a `private` type.

A nested type does *not* belong to an *instance* of the enclosing type.  So if you define `language` as a `static` property of `Member`, then it has one value for `class Member`, regardless of how many instances of `Population` you have with different languages.

What you want is for each instance of `Member` to have the `language` of the `Population` to which it belongs.  You can accomplish that a couple of different ways, but they all involve storing *something* in `Member`.

Option 1.  Make `language` an instance property of `Member`, and set it in `Member.init(language: String)`.

Option 2. Store a reference to the `Population` to which the `Member` belongs (I'll assume it's `let population: Population`), and make `language` a *computed* property which returns `population.language`.

Option 2 is more flexible, because you can leverage having the population to fetch other `Member` values that it gets from its `Population`, but it requires some careful consideration.   Does it make sense in your app for a `Member` to exist outside of a `Population`?  If yes, then you probably want to define it like `weak var population: Population?`.  If no, a `Member` cannot exist outside of a `Population`, then `unowned let population: Population` could be preferred (though the `weak` version could be used too).   The point here is to avoid reference cycles that would cause a memory leak.

So maybe something like this:

```swift
class Population {
    var language: String
    var members: [Member] = []
    
    init(language: String) {
        self.language = language
        for _ in 1...10 {members.append(Member(population: self))}
    }
    
    class Member {
        unowned let population: Population
        var language: String { population.language }

        init(population: Population) { self.population = population }
        
        func speak() {
            switch self.language {
                case "english": print("speak some English")
                case "german" : print("spreche ein Bißchen deutsch")
                // other cases go here
                default: print("mmmm mmmm mmm mmm") // I'm a mute
            }
        }
        
        func write() {
            switch self.language {
                case "english": print("write some English")
                case "german" : print("schreibe ein Bißchen deutsch")
                // other cases go here
                default: print("h8hta;lushgaih9732 8@#Y"); // Can't write
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Though off-topic, I would recommend making language an `enum`, Then you can remove the `default` cases from the `switch` statements, and the compiler will helpfully, though not tactfully, show you all of the `switch` statements that need to be updated when you add a new language.  If you like you can even make the `enum` based on `String` so you can still access the `String` value wherever that might be useful:

```swift
    enum Language: String
    {
        case arabic     = "arabic"
        case chinese    = "chinese"
        case english    = "english"
        case french     = "french"
        case german     = "german"
        case japanese   = "japanese"
        case portuguese = "portuguese"
        case spanish    = "spanish"
        // etc...
    }
```

Then if you want the string value you can refer to `language.rawValue`

Comment: Thanks. I see you point about having `language` being equal across members of all populations in my initial example - thats indeed not the intention. You option 2 seems already quite good. If I understand correctly however, this would save one reference to `population' per instance of member. Doesn't this sacrifice quite some space in case I got many members? So couldn't this somehow be saved in a more 'static' way? Does this make sense?

Comment: One more question: If I would go with option b, I could also just always use `self.population.language` instead of the calculated property `self.language`. Whilst this looks a bit less neat, is there a reason to do so in order for it to work faster?

Comment: If you need to be able to obtain a `language` from a`Member` you’re going to have to pay for that one way or another.  You’re choices are to pay for it in time or in space.  Obviously my suggestions pay for it space.  You could also provide an external mapping such as in a `Dictionary` from `Member` to `Population` but that doesn’t save any space and actually may require slightly more.  You could pay for it in time by iterating over your `Population`s looking for a specific `Member`.  That seems wasteful to me, but if you’re that short on RAM, I suppose it could be a reasonable trade off.

Comment: As for the other question, sure you definitely could eliminate the computed property, and just always access the language directly through the `Member`’s `population`.   In some sense though, language is actually a property of `Member`, and accessing it via its `Population` is an implementation detail that code that uses `Member` ought not be concerned with.   Within the same module the getter function will be optimized away in release builds.  In you’re worried about the getter call overhead between modules look into the `@inlinable` keyword.

Comment: Unless you’re planning to have  billions of `Member` instances or are on a platform with really constrained RAM (Raspberry Pi maybe?) concerning yourself with an extra property in `Member` isn’t something to be concerned about until profiling gives you data proving to you it’s a problem.  Honestly the biggest waste is the dynamic allocation overhead of so many individual memory blocks that using a `class` implies.

Comment: Another performance consideration is to think about whether you intend for there to be subclasses of`Population` and `Member`.  If not, consider marking them as `final`. That enables the compiler to do lots of optimizations that it couldn’t if it had to allow for polymorphic behavior.